# Laravel: Pass in Model instance or only the id as an argument to a Model function?

Tags: laravel, model

Suppose I have:

```
class User extends Model {
   ...
   public function sendFriendRequestTo($user){
       // $user represents another User instance
   }
}
```

My guess is that it is better to always pass in simply the id of the Model object and retrieve the record corresponding to that id from inside the function. This ensures that our data is synchronized.

Is there such a thing as a best practice in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

As OOP dependency inversion principle (D in SOLID) said you should inject your dependency in that method and i think inject that instance is better way.